# How do i read a boolean value?

Tags: c#, boolean

I'm making the basis of my app I want to make, but there's a problem with how I'm selecting what friend the user may want to talk to in this "prototype" (i guess its a prototype?)

```
string friend;
string friend2;
string friend3;
bool option;

Console.WriteLine("Who would you like to talk to first? " + friend + ", " + friend2 + ", " + friend3);

option = (Console.ReadLine);

if(option = friend)
{

}
```

and that's the code of the issue. Should I remove it or can someone help?

Comment: I think you should start with c# basics like syntax.

Comment: `if(option == friend)`  the problem is when using an equal sign, one means assignment, two means test for equality.

Comment: bool to string comparison is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`option` variable should be of type `string` in your case.
Then, You need to change this bit (assignment operator)

```cs
if(option = friend)
```

to this (comparison operator)

```cs
if(option == friend)
```

So finally you will get (after readline command fix)

```cs
string friend;
string friend2;
string friend3;
string option;

Console.WriteLine("Who would you like to talk to first? " + friend + ", " + friend2 + ", " + friend3);

option = Console.ReadLine();

if(option == friend)
{

}
```

Have fun!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are a little confused, You are using an assignment operator instead of a comparison operator.

Here an example

```
int a = 1 + 2 + 3;
int b = 6;
Console.WriteLine(a == b);  // output: True

char c1 = 'a';
char c2 = 'A';
Console.WriteLine(c1 == c2);  // output: False
Console.WriteLine(c1 == char.ToLower(c2));  // output: True
```

Also you can read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators

Comment: while OP _certainly_ should learn what you're writing, your answer does not actually _answer_ the question OP posted. please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)